Is there a terse way to write this conditional expression in C#
Is there a terse way to write the same in C#, say using null conditional or null coalescing operator? I seem to be missing something here with the null conditional operator usage.
//var hopefullySomeBool = (bool)someClassVariable.ChildClassProperty?.SomeStringProperty?.Contains("Blah");

internal class SomeClass
{ 
    public SomeChildClass ChildClassProperty { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeChildClass
{
    public string SomeStringProperty { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass someClassVariable = new SomeClass();

        if (    someClassVariable.ChildClassProperty != null 
             && someClassVariable.ChildClassProperty.SomeStringProperty != null 
             && someClassVariable.ChildClassProperty.SomeStringProperty.Contains("Blah")
           ) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found Blah");
        }
   
        Console.WriteLine("Blah not found");
    }        
}


Maybe this?
var result = someClassVariable
    .ChildClassProperty?
    .SomeStringProperty?
    .Contains("Blah") == true 
        ? "found Blah" 
        : "Blah not found";

Console.WriteLine(result);

Be aware that the null-conditional-operator returns Nullable<T>, so the left-hand side of your ==-operator is Nullable<bool>, not just bool. This is why you need to write Contains("Blah") == true instead of just using Contains("Blah").
Furthermore the ternary always returns something. You cannot use it in a void-returning expression such as Console.WriteLine. So this won't compile:
mycondition ? Console.WriteLine("One") : Console.WriteLine("Two");

